# How can I save the admin user in wagtail's admin?

Tags: wagtail

I have a non-Page model in a wagtail application that I'd like to create a history for, something like `my_object` and `my_object_history`, where on any create, edit, or delete in the admin a new `my_object_history` model is created with the admin user that was created, the time, etc.

```
class MyObjectHistory(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, editable=False,null=True,blank=True)
    save_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    my_object = models.ForeignKey(MyObject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

And then somewhere, on a `save...` event ideally, I'd instantiate this object and save it.

I'm unclear on where I can override the wagtail admin and get the request user to assign and save.

The django `ModelAdmin` has a [save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model), but doesn't appear wagtail has anything similar.

I started down overriding `EditView`/`CreateView` [path](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1.1/reference/contrib/modeladmin/primer.html#modeladmin-overriding-views), but it doesn't appear that [EditView](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/views.py#L703) actually has a `save` method.

The model itself has a `save` method I can use, but no reference to the `request.user` so I'd need to get that somewhere.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

This really wasn't a wagtail issue, the key was to use django's standard [`form_valid`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/) method:

```
class MyObjectEditView(EditView):
    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        history = MyObjectHistory.objects.create(created_by=self.request.user, item=self.instance)
        history.save()
        return super().form_valid(form, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I'm not 100% on this (and pretty late), but would this EditView actually create a new MyObjectHistory object every time rather than edit the current instance of MyObjectHistory? If that would be the case, seemingly a get_object_or_404 or a similar method could be used to rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

this is how I solved my problem  after looking at the edit_view function in [wagtail](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/options.py)  ModelAdmin(WagtailRegisterable):

```
class MymodelAdmin(ModelAdmin):

def edit_view(self, request, instance_pk):
    kwargs = {'model_admin': self, 'instance_pk': instance_pk}
    view_class = self.edit_view_class
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        mymodel = myModel.objects.get(pk=instance_pk)
```